# How to remove least frequent tuples from dict of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict D of lists of pairs (tuples), that has similar form to this example:

```
D = {'1': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)], 
     '2': [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)], 
     '3': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2)] 
}
```

What I want to do is count pair frequency and only **keep tuples that appear more than once**.

So the desired output would be:

```
D = {'1': [(0, 0), (1, 1)],  
     '2': [(0, 0), (1, 1)],  
     '3': [(0, 0)] 
}
```

I tried `[k for k, v in Counter(D).items() if v >= 1]`, but only works for list of lists, which is not desirable in this case, because I need to keep the keys.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is an easy solution

Comment: I'm already using Counter, but that 'explodes' the dictionary

Comment: @SurajSubramanian no, what matter is the frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
D = {'1': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)], 
     '2': [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)], 
     '3': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2)] 
}
```

Try this :

```
all_tuples = [t for key in D for t in D[key]]
selected_tuples = list(set([t for t in all_tuples if all_tuples.count(t)>1]))
output = {key : [t for t in D[key] if t in selected_tuples] for key in D}
```

**Output :**

```
>>output
{'1': [(0, 0), (1, 1)], '2': [(0, 0), (1, 1)], '3': [(0, 0)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make another dictionary which holds "tuple : frequency", go through all of them, and each time you find new one, add it with frequency = 1, otherwise increment it, and then later you can just go through them again, and if the frequency is less then 2 remove them.
This isn't the most efficient method, but if you don't have hundreds of thousands of entries it should to the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using `collections.Counter`, first count all tuples, then remove if necessary:

```
from collections import Counter

D = {'1': [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
     '2': [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)],
     '3': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 2)]
}

all_tuples = [t for k,v in D.items() for t in v]
C = Counter(all_tuples)
D2 = {}
for k,v in D.items():
    D2[k] = [t for t in v if C[t]>1]
print(D2)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [(0, 0), (1, 1)], 
 '2': [(0, 0), (1, 1)],
 '3': [(0, 0)]}
```

Comment: You could also just modify `D` in the loop.